# Iterator for vector of pointers that returns a reference

Tags: c++, iterator

I am writing a non-owning wrapper class for a list of objects. Using a list of pointers internally seems to make the most sense for my situation so my class looks something like this:

```
class MyWrapper {
    std::vector<MyObject *> m_objs;
};
```

Now I want the wrapper to be iterable and since I don't want to write my own iterator-type, I'm reusing the vector's one:

```
class MyWrapper {
    std::vector<MyObject *> m_objs;
    
    std::vector<MyObject *>::iterator begin();
    std::vector<MyObject *>::iterator end();
};
```

The problem with this approach is that this will of course yield an iterator that will produce a pointer-type when dereferenced. However I would like to let the iterator dereference to a reference of the underlying object though.

So essentially I want an iterator that dereferences the pointer it is pointing to and thus instead of returning the pointer, it will return a reference to the underlying object. In code:

```
MyObject &test = *it;
```

Is there some iterator-magic that I can play here that lets me achieve something like this without having to write a custom iterator?

Comment: Have you considered changing your vector to hold `std::reference_wrapper< MyObject>` instead of a raw pointer?

Comment: example https://godbolt.org/z/W71Psq8P6

Comment: If you have boost, you don't need to write it yourself, it's [`boost::indirect_iterator`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/iterator/doc/html/iterator/specialized/indirect.html)

Comment: @Caleth ah yes that was exactly what I was looking for! I stumbled upon this some time back but couldn't remember what it is called and as such I was unable to find it again xD

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis not yet, no. I have to think  about whether this breaks anything for my use case but on first glance this seems like an even better approach that using the indirect iterator. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I think both solutions (indirect iterator) +  the reference_wrapper should be added as answers to this question. I'll mark the indirect iterator one as the accepted one since that directly answers the question at hand. However using the wrapper instead might also be a useful hint for anyone stumbling on this question at some point.